# How to capture stdout of shell after switching users

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm making a shell with python. So far I have gotten `cd` to work (not pretty I know, but it's all I need for now). When I `su root` (for example) I get a root shell, but I can't capture the output I receive after running a command. However the shell does accept my commands, as when I type `exit` it exits. Is there a way to capture the output of a 'new' shell?

```py
import os, subprocess

while True:
    command = input("$ ")
    if len(command.split(" ")) >= 2:
        print(command.split(" ")[0])  #This line is for debugging
        if command.split(" ")[0] == "cd" or command.split(" ")[1] == "cd":
            os.chdir(command.split(" ")[command.split(" ").index("cd") + 1])
            continue
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    print(output.strip("\n"))
```

EDIT: To make my request a bit more precise, I'd like a way to authenticate as another user from a python script, basically catching the authentication, doing it in the background and then starting a new subprocess.

Comment: You are not makeing a new shell, subprocess executes commands within sh shell, as it is the default. Some commands do not write to stdout. Can you give an example which command you are trying to execute ?

Comment: trying `su root`, authenticating spawns a regular bash shell which is outside the script; then when you exit it you are back in the script. I know this as the script doesn't have variables like `~` and `-` saved, but `cd`ing into these directories works for the spawned shell.

Comment: Note that `str.split(" ")` is deeply oversimplified and not at all how the shell actually works. To do shell-like quoting right you need to handle backslashes, quoted strings, strings that change quoting styles within them, etc etc. There's an implementation of POSIX-y string splitting built into the Python standard's `shlex` module; reading its source code would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to understand how `subprocess.Popen` works. This command executes a new sub-process (on a Unix machine, calls `fork` and then `exec`). The new sub-process is a separate process. Your code just calls `communicate` once and then discards of it.

If you just create a new shell by calling `subprocess.Popen` and then running `su <user>` inside of it, the shell will be closed right after that and the next time, you'll be running the command using the same (original) user again.

What you want is probably to create a single subprocess at the beginning of your application and then be a sort of a proxy between the user and the underlying process, and then just keep writing to its `stdin` and reading from `stdout`.

Here's an example:

```
import os, subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,                                                                                                                                                               
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

while True:
    command = input("$ ")
    process.stdin.write(command + "\n")
    process.stdin.flush()
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    print(output.strip("\n"))
```

(I removed the `cd` command parsing bit because it wasn't constructive to understanding the solution here, but you can definitely add specific handlers for specific inputs that wrap the underlying shell)

Comment: Thanks for that, I get how it works now and was able to complete my project using the same principles but in C++